# Wordpress Header Location error

Tags: php, wordpress, header

I am getting below error on my website :

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /XXXXX/public_html/index.php:1) in /XXXXX/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1121
```

I have checked `wp-config.php` file's PHP open and end tag is proper without space. As well as `functions.php` file is fine.

Please help me in this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using the search http://bit.ly/ZPDqvr its answered many times already http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Warning%3A+Cannot+modify+header+information+-+headers+already+sent+by

Comment: Recheck all modifications that were made to the site since it was last working. One of the modifications is producing output (an error, an echo statement, etc) when it shouldn't be doing so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: I m thinking why it shows that error in index.php but I have not done anything in index.php file

Comment: I have also tried by putting ob_start(); and ob_flush(); in config.php as well as function.php file. But didn't worked for me.

Comment: index.php uses several other scripts to create the site. You need to check modifications to _all_ of them, or at the very least, to all of them that have the potential to be called from index.php.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any redirect or wp_redirect methods called in your code(in all your theme's files). If you have them, Move them above all HTML tags if possible. That should fix them.